# VBA using .click on getelment by id keeps loading

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating a script using VBA in excel to open a webpage in internet explorer and push data from Excel to submit the page and move to the next one.

In addition to pushing data to replace the unit image file by clicking the remove button:
[The remove button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwJ6D.jpg)

and its code as following :

```
<button type="submit" id="edit-field-building-autocad-img-und-0-remove-button" name="field_building_autocad_img_und_0_remove_button" value="remove" class="btn btn-danger form-submit icon-before ajax-processed ladda-button button btn-sm delete-file-btn" data-style="zoom-in" data-spinner-color="#000" data-spinner-lines="12"><span class="ladda-label"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>  remove</span><span class="ladda-spinner"></span></button>
```

I use the button id with the .click

It should look like that after I click the button:
[afer clicking the remove button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxAZB.jpg)

But it just keeps loading and looks that way:
[Keep loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aovyc.jpg)

My code:

Sub PushDataMoh()

```
Dim IE  As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim wsb As Worksheet: Set wsb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
Dim pn     'page number
Dim mypage 'The default page
Dim RowCount
Dim UnitNum
Dim LevelNum


For RowCount = 2 To 4
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    pn = wsb.Range("A" & RowCount).Value
    mypage = "https://" & pn & "/edit/320189/320225"
    IE.Navigate mypage

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.Document
    Set submit = doc.getElementById("edit-submit")
    Set del = doc.getElementById("edit-field-building-autocad-img-und-0-remove-button")

    UnitNum = doc.getElementById("edit-field-unit-no-und-0-value").Value   'Get unit number
    LevelNum = doc.getElementById("edit-field-floor-no-und-0-value").Value  'Get Level number
    NameCheck = "The Unit number is " & UnitNum & " the level number is " & LevelNum
    Debug.Print NameCheck

    doc.getElementById("edit-field-north-side-und-0-value").Value = wsb.Range("E" & RowCount).Value     'Get North
    doc.getElementById("edit-field-east-side-und-0-value").Value = wsb.Range("F" & RowCount).Value      'Get East
    doc.getElementById("edit-field-south-side-und-0-value").Value = wsb.Range("G" & RowCount).Value     'Get South
    doc.getElementById("edit-field-west-side-und-0-value").Value = wsb.Range("H" & RowCount).Value      'Get West

    del.Click

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
    Loop

    Set choseFile = doc.getElementById("edit-field-building-autocad-img-und-0-upload")
    Set upload = doc.getElementById("edit-field-building-autocad-img-und-0-upload-button")

    choseFile.Click
    upload.Click

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    submit.Click

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    'RowCount.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    'IE.Quit

Next
```

End Sub

The HTML code as following:

```
<div class="file-widget form-managed-file clearfix col-md-9 files-cont"><input type="hidden" name="field_building_autocad_img[und][0][fid]" value="820983">
<input type="hidden" name="field_building_autocad_img[und][0][display]" value="1">
<span class="file"><img class="file-icon" alt="Image icon" title="image/png" src="/modules/file/icons/image-x-generic.png"> <a href="https://subdivision-services.housing.gov.sa/sites/default/files/1577728621274522778-test_part1-11_3.png" type="image/png; length=508614">1577728621274522778-test_part1-11_3.png</a></span>  <span class="file-size badge">496.69 كيلوبايت</span><button type="submit" id="edit-field-building-autocad-img-und-0-remove-button" name="field_building_autocad_img_und_0_remove_button" value="حذف" class="btn btn-danger form-submit icon-before ajax-processed ladda-button button btn-sm delete-file-btn" data-style="zoom-in" data-spinner-color="#000" data-spinner-lines="12"><span class="ladda-label"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 حذف</span><span class="ladda-spinner"></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like we also need your CSS code to see the loading effect. If after removing the file you are trying to upload the new file then you may have the issues with it. Because due to security reasons, the IE browser will not allow you to automate the file upload control and it can also be the possible cause for this issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the security reason I have to choose the file manually when the chooseFile is clicked a browse window open and I choose the file. but the issue is with the remove button when I click on it using the mouse it works but when I use .click with getelemebtby id or getelementbyclassname it just keeps loading at the attached @Deepak-MSFT pictures

Comment: Test it manually and using code and after that check the source code using developer tools to see the difference in a code while using these 2 approaches. See whether any CSS class is causing this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm new to programming I have been using VBA for less than a week to help with this task, the only thing i noticed when I clicked manually on the remove button that an attribute was added disabled = "disabled" it was not there before I click on the button @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: Please check in your HTML code whether it fires any event while you click on the remove button. If there is any event then try to dispatch that event using VBA code after .click. You can try to share some more HTML code. We can help you to check for that event.

Comment: I tried dispatchEvent and fireEvent, it didn't work or maybe I did it the wrong way, I posted the HTML code, the issue happen with the del.click element id "edit-field-building-autocad-img-und-0-remove-button", I apperciate the help thanks @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: I tried different other methods I saw in other forms but still the same, some say Internet explorer has a special way to create event or fire event @Deepak-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to refer to this example may help to dispatch the event correctly.

```
Option Explicit

'It works with Excel 32 bit and Excel 64 bit
#If Win64 Then
  'For 64 bit systems
  Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
  'For 32 bit systems
 ' Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Sub test()

Dim url As String
Dim browser As Object
Dim btn As Object

  url = "https://example.com"

  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  Set btn = browser.document.getElementById("btn1")
  btn.Focus

  'btn.Click

  Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, btn, "click")

End Sub

Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

You can try to modify the sample and try to make a test on your end and let us know about your test results. Whether it works or not.